# Loading usercontrols on demand under jquery tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, user-controls, asp.net-ajax

I have few jquery tabs on a usercontrol that loads a separate user control under each. Each user control is unique. It all works fine right now but the overall page response is too slow. In order to improve performance I am trying to load few user controls under these tabs on demand (that is on click of tab). Possibly without post back... ajaxish.
Can anyone guide me?
I tried to follow [this](http://encosia.com/boost-aspnet-performance-with-deferred-content-loading/) tutorial and [this](http://www.aspxtutorial.com/post/2011/01/02/Load-aspnet-web-user-control-using-jQuery-and-web-method.aspx) one too but did not have any success. I have attached the code for parent usercontrol.

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li class="active">Rewards</li>
<li id="liCoupons">Coupons</li>
<li id="liLibrary">Library</li>
<li id="liProducts">Favorite</li>
<li id="liPreferences">Preferences</li></ul><ul id="tabPanes" class="rewardsTabs">
<li>
    <div class="wrapper active">
        <uc:Rewards ID="wellness" runat="server" />

    </div>
</li>
<li id="liCoupons">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <uc:Coupon runat="server" />
    </div>
</li><li id="liLibrary">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <uc:Library runat="server" />
    </div>
</li><li id="liProducts">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <uc:Products runat="server" />
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="preferences">
            <uc:Preferences runat="server"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: basically I am looking to load a usercontrol on demand when a tab is clicked. without a postback or in updatepanel so that the user doesn't see whole page load. preferably with a loading spinner.

Comment: What do you have in your `UserControl`s? Are you checking permission levels or some sort of user group to generate different menu items?

Comment: Menu items are same for all users. They do not have any checks on permissions or anything. They are same for all users except the data in it (ex: account information0

Comment: Can you post some code from one of them? I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to handle this that would allow you to remove the `UserControl`s and do something slightly different, like write an entire ASP.NET page that builds the menu, and then load that page via AJAX. I'd suggest something similar using the `UserControl`s, but I've never used AJAX with them.

Comment: I do not have the code handy right now, but they are just regular UCs. some have buttons with postback action, some have form fields and button with ajax post. They are very independent. If you insist on code, I will put it here when I get home (6pm EST).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [second link](http://www.aspxtutorial.com/post/2011/01/02/Load-aspnet-web-user-control-using-jQuery-and-web-method.aspx) you mentioned should work. You don't need to define any user controls in your markup.

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li class="active">Rewards</li>
    <li id="liCoupons">Coupons</li>
    <li id="liLibrary">Library</li>
    <li id="liProducts">Favorite</li>
    <li id="liPreferences">Preferences</li>
</ul>
<div id="results" class="wrapper"></div>
```

Each tab click will do an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Default.aspx/WebMetodToCall", 
       data: data, // I wouldn't prefer passing webmethod name here
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
           $('#result').html(msg.d);
       },
       failure: function (msg) 
           //error
       }
   });
```

to the web methods.

```
[WebMethod]
   public static string Rewards()
   {
       return RenderControl("~/controls/rewardsControl.ascx");
   }

[WebMethod]
   public static string Coupons()
   {
       return RenderControl("~/controls/couponsControl.ascx");
   }    
...
```

Each method will render only the requested control. Also in your method you can keep or extract the viewstate depending on your needs. After rendering, the webmethod should pass back the html string to be injected into the placeholders.

If you tried this and were successful rendering one control at a time but still seeing slowness then you have some back end issues while getting the data. If your controls are data heavy I would recommend doing some server side caching.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is good... how do we do the tab click? like this? <li><a href="...webservices/ControlServce.svc/Content?cType=Rewards" class="wrapper active"></a></li>

Comment: I think this is a little smelly (tying one AJAX method to several WebMethods), but overall is the best solution posted here (especially given the special set of circumstances in the question).

Comment: @xoail you can just bind the click event using jquery to whatever DOM element you want. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @jwiscarson Not sure why it is smelly , it suits the single responsibility principle. Also, i would move the handling of loading the control to a different class so keep the webmethod class lighter.

Comment: @zero7 Can I use a .ashx handler instead of WebMethod? If so, will the method be same? The reason I ask is, I already have a Service.ashx file and I can extended it for this case.

Comment: @xoail actually that is what asp.net ajax web extensions do that for you when you call the web method. Take a look at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx.

Comment: @zero7, I think it's questionable that it suits the single responsibility principle, but I don't think it's extremely bad or anything. I really did mean it's just a little smelly because the results from the AJAX function change depending on the WebMethod called -- it's not a consistent object or DOM hierarchy (necessarily) either. Regardless, I do think it's the best option and the least amount of overhaul for the given circumstances (and I up-voted you to reflect that).

Answer (score 6):

Does your user controls rely on post-backs and view-state for there working? It will be relative easy to fetch the user control HTML to be displayed in the tab using AJAX but then post-back on that control will send the entire data to the actual page (that may not have the user control loaded). So the basic outline would be

1. Track the active tab using hidden variable or view-state.
2. Load the user control based on active tab in the early page cycle. The best bet would be init stage (not that view-state won't be available here, so you have to store active tab in hidden variable and access it via Request.Forms collection).
3. Give each user control a ID and it should be different from tab to tab. ID is very important for loading the view-state.
4. If you get corrupted view-state errors at tab switching then you need to first load the user control for the previous tab and then at later page stage (say load/prerender), unload it and load new user control for active tab.
5. You can use a placeholder or panel control within each tab pane to load the user control in the correct location.
6. Needless to say, on change of jquery tab, you need to submit your form using post-back script. After every post-back, you need to have a script to re-initialize tabs and selecting active tab.
7. For better user experience, put entire thing into an UpdatePanel.

Comment: I dont think I need view state for their working. Do you have any sample code or point me to someplace?

Answer (score 5):

perhaps use an anchor that points to the service defined below.  For instance,

```
<li><a href="...webservices/ControlServce.svc/Content?cType=Rewards" class="wrapper active"></a></li> 

/// <summary>
/// Service used by ajax for loading social media content
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ControlService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Streams html content
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">type of control</param>
    /// <returns>html stream of content</returns>
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Content?cType={cType}")]
    public Stream GetContent(string cType)
    {
        var tw = new StringWriter();
        var writer = new Html32TextWriter(tw);

        var page = new Page();
        var control = page.LoadControl(cType);

        control.RenderControl(writer);

        writer.Close();

        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tw.ToString()));

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some sample code? JS and code to spit out html via ashx handler?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to make an Ajax call in order to make this.
now you have options to call AJAX:

1 - Call via SOAP web service (ASP AjaxScriptManager referencing will be needed for every web method).

2- Call via WCF Service as the previous answer.

3 - Call via Rest service.

4- Call via Jquery ajax method but the request must going to external page like "Actions.aspx" so when you call your method an HTTPRequest will be made into Actions page then it will have the returned data within its response. `$.Ajax(url,data,action,successMethod); // this is the fastest way I tried them all.`

Here is what you should to do:
1- on the change tab event call your method by using the appropriate Ajax calling method from the above options.

2- from the success method use the returned data but it's better for you to use eval(data) for the DataTime objects.

here is some example explains how to make this call:

```
var helper = {
callAjax: function(sentData, successFun) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/Actions.aspx",
            type: "Get",
            data: sentData,
            cache: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFun
        });
    }
};

helper.callAjax('request=getCities&countryID=' + countryID, function (args) {
   var result = eval(args); // this object will contain the returned data
var htmlData = '';
    for (var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    // write your HTML code by jQuery like this
    htmlData  += '<div>' +  result[i].title + '</div>';
}
$('#tab3').html(htmlData);
});
```

now at the Actions.ASPX code use the following:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object _return = new
        {
            error = "",
            status = true
        };
        JavaScriptSerializer _serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string str = Request.QueryString["request"].ToString();
            switch (str.ToLower())
            {
case "getcities":
                    int countryID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["countryID"].ToString());
                    _return = JQueryJson.Core.City.getAllCitiesByCountry(countryID).Select(_city => new
                    {
                        id = _city.ID,
                        title = _city.Name
                    });
                    _serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                    Response.ContentType = "text/json";
                    Response.Write(_serializer.Serialize(_return));
                    break;
}
// etc........
}
```

Comment: Thanks... unfortunately in your answer I see that you are returning json not the usercontrol it self. With $.ajax, can I use .ashx handler and return usercontrol markup?

Answer (score 3):

If you adjust it a little with jquery, this should work:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2007/06/13/how-to-make-tab-control-panels-load-on-demand.aspx

Or you just use the asp.net tabs.

Answer (score 3):

You should go for the second link using jquery and webmethod. That way you will actually populate the tabs on demand without making you page heavy.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the fastest solution to your problem (but not necessarily the best long-term) is to wrap all your `UserControl`s in a .aspx page. In this situation, you'd just have to move your parent `UserControl` markup to a new .aspx page, and call it via AJAX.

Assuming that you called this page something like **Menu.aspx**, and further assuming that you don't need any data passed into this page (that is, it can track all of its own data internally), your jQuery AJAX call would look something like this:

```
function GetMenu ($placeholder) {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
        url: "Menu.aspx",
        done: function (result) {
            $placeholder.html(result.d);
        },
        fail: function () {
            $placeholder.html("Error loading menu.");
        }
    });
}
```

Some notes:

1. `done` and `fail` will replace `success` and `error` in jQuery 1.8, so any jQuery AJAX you use should plan for this transition.
2. I wrapped this in a function largely because I prefer to put AJAX calls inside JS classes and functions, and then reference those objects. With a menu, it's unlikely you'd have several different pages loading the same data via AJAX (since this will be on some sort of master page, I'm guessing), but it's always good to get yourself in the habit of doing these things.
3. Depending on your feelings about tightly-coupled HTML/JavaScript, you could replace `$placeholder` above with a callback function. Calling that from your the page where your menu resides would look something like:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       GetMenu(MenuCallback);
   });

   function MenuCallback(menuHtml) {
       $("#menu").html(menuHtml); // I'm assuming the ID of your ul/span/div tag here.
   }
   ```
4. Some people (myself included) use the `$` prefix to differentiate between JavaScript and jQuery variables. So here, `$placeholder` is a jQuery variable.
5. You might be able to re-write this `$.ajax` call as a `type: "GET"`, which would be a little bit more efficient, but I'm not sure if the `UserControl`s would cause problems in that regard. Normally, if I'm loading an entire .aspx page via AJAX, I use `GET` instead of `POST`. You don't have to change much to try it out: just switch out the `type` property and change `result.d` to `result`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution is to implement client call back

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210.aspx

When user clicks on some tab,onclick event calls js func with name of tab as parameter, than that tab calls server code with same parameter.

Than in code you load controls you want depending which tab is clicked.
Now you need to render controls into html and send tham back to js function.
Now you have controls in js function, find where you want to insert code an insert it.

that should work in theory and it is not to complicated :))

Answer (score 0):

an asnwer (not mine) to this question is probably useful to you:

[Asynchronous loading of user controls in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295995/asynchronous-loading-of-user-controls-in-a-page)

it states that there are problems with this with needing a form on the user control to post back, but that should be ok to have independent forms with ajax post.  you'll have to think about what happens when posting the form(s) on the page, but shouldn't be insurmountable.  shouldn't be any reason you couldn't just make it the ashx handler you have mentioned.