# Asynchronous loading of user controls in a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, user-controls, updatepanel

I have created a page to display multiple user controls inside update panels. Some user controls will get loaded faster and some may take a longer time to load. Now when the page loads, it waits for all the user controls to get loaded and display the page only after that. But I want to load the user controls asynchronously with a loader image for each of them so that the light weight user controls will get loaded easily without waiting for the heavier ones.

Please help me to find a solution.

---

I have successfully loaded the user control into my page using the above method. However now i am facing difficulty in loading usercontrols containing ajax controls such as tab container, calender extender etc..

Is there any work around for this problem

Comment: Please look out these useful links which claim to solve the problem: - ["Asynchronous methods and user controls"](http://forums.asp.net/t/1468026.aspx/1)
- ["ASP.NET – Asynchronous User Control"](http://rsuharta.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/asp-net-asynchronous-user-control/)

Answer (score 8):

You will run into a bunch of issues: ViewState, controls needing form tags, postbacks will not work but if you are doing this with a control that is purely a `View` it will work fine.

**Script:**

```
//use .ready() or pageLoad() and pass params etc if you need to
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Default.aspx/GetControlViaAjax',
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {  
      $('#yourdiv').html(data.d);
    }
 });
```

**WebMethod:**

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetControlViaAjax()
    {
        //example public properties, send null if you don't have any
        Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        d.Add("CssClass", "YourCSSClass");
        d.Add("Title", "Your title");
        return RenderUserControl("/yourcontrol.ascx", true, d, null, null);
        //use this one if your controls are compiled into a .dll
        //return RenderUserControl(null, true, d, "Com.YourNameSpace.UI", "AwesomeControl");

    }
```

**Render method:**

```
    private static string RenderUserControl(string path, bool useFormLess,
         Dictionary<string, object> controlParams, string assemblyName, string controlName )
    {

        Page pageHolder = null;
        if (useFormLess)
        {
            pageHolder = new FormlessPage() { AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath }; //needed to resolve "~/"
        }
        else
        {
            pageHolder = new Page() { AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath };
        }

        UserControl viewControl = null;

        //use path by default
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {    
            //load assembly and usercontrol when .ascx is compiled into a .dll        
            string controlAssemblyName = string.Format("{0}.{1},{0}", assemblyName, controlName );

            Type type = Type.GetType(controlAssemblyName);            
            viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(type, null);
        }
        else
        {
            viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);    

        }              

        viewControl.EnableViewState = false;

        if (controlParams != null && controlParams.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var pair in controlParams)
            {
                Type viewControlType = viewControl.GetType();
                PropertyInfo property =
                   viewControlType.GetProperty(pair.Key);

                if (property != null)
                {
                    property.SetValue(viewControl, pair.Value, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format(
                       "UserControl: {0} does not have a public {1} property.",
                       path, pair.Key));
                }
            }
        }

        if (useFormLess)
        {                
            pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);
        }
        else
        {
            HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
            form.Controls.Add(viewControl);
            pageHolder.Controls.Add(form);
        }
        StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);
        return output.ToString();
    }
```

**FormlessPage class:**

```
    public class FormlessPage : Page
    {
        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: The above code gives me an error as follows.. An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(System.Type, object[])'

Comment: Where should I write the Render method? In the page or in the usercontrol? Also where will be the code to fill the data into the usercontrol? I am very new to the user control. So it would be better if you could explain the above method a little more.. Many thanks..

Comment: This is extremely advanced if you are just learning how to write UserControls.

Comment: Have 2 queries. 1. Whats the use of the properties CssClass and title. 2. When I put the whole thing in the .cs file i am getting the error "error executing child request for handler formless page". Its happening on the line   HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false); Please tell me what I am doing wrong..

Comment: Hi.. I have successfully loaded the user control into my page using the above method. However now i am facing difficulty in loading usercontrols containing ajax controls such as tab container, calender extender etc.. Is there any work around for the problem

Answer (score 0):

user controls are probably not the right answer, as they are meant for server side composition.  you probably need some standalone (in the sense of being served up independently) components on the server that serve the html fragments you need so that you can request them with javascript and shove the result into the larger page.